# Type-Inference with symbols not working as expected

Tags: typescript

Can someone please help me how I can achieve the expected behavior as described in my last source code comment?

```js
// pre-test: working as intended

const symbol1 = Symbol(1)

const symbol2 = Symbol(2)

function take(symbol: typeof symbol1) {
}

take(symbol1); // no error

take(symbol2); // error (correct)

// problem description

const symbol3: unique symbol = Symbol(3)

function getRecord(key: string | typeof symbol3) {
  return { [key]: true };
}

const myRecord = getRecord(symbol3); // myRecord is incorrectly inferred as
                                     //   { [x: string]: boolean }
                                     // expected:
                                     //   { [x: typeof symbol3]: true }
```

I am just totally lost how to deal with them, as I don't really get the [idea as described in the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use overloads seeing that you want different return types for different inputs. Of course, a conditional type could work but it just has unnecessary complications.

```
function getRecord(key: string): { [key: string]: true }
function getRecord(key: typeof symbol3): { [K in typeof symbol3]: true }
function getRecord(key: string | typeof symbol3) {
  return { [key]: true };
}
```

The only thing notable would be the use of a mapped type. This is required since `{ [key: typeof symbol3]: true }` is illegal (and the error even asks you to use a mapped type).

Now, this *does* work and produces the right output... but now you get a peculiar error:

```
//    ~~~~~~~~ error
const myRecord = getRecord(symbol3);
//    ^? { [symbol3]: true; }
```

The error reads:

> The type of this node cannot be serialized because its property '[symbol3]' cannot be serialized.

Looking into this yields [ms/TS#50720](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50720) and proposes the following workaround:

```
type WithSymbol3<T> = {
    readonly [K in typeof symbol3]: T;
}

function getRecord(key: string): { [key: string]: true }
function getRecord(key: typeof symbol3): WithSymbol3<true>;
function getRecord(key: string | typeof symbol3) {
  return { [key]: true };
}
```

It works without any errors now, but a small downside is that the type in the hint is `WithSymbol3<true>` which is mildly annoying. It's still effectively the same result, though.

```
const myRecord = getRecord(symbol3);
//    ^? WithSymbol3<true>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAhgTwLYCMIBsCMCC8CAymplgBQ4CUooksiKG2ATAcaduSzSKAGYBXKGDgBLaAjgBDANYBTckzIAuKcgAO8iPySdcVBAG9QAX1ogZCpfuoBuBAHpHCKBATyATp4ieLVxWVWKgdnD29fBHJIb3lRXlAwjR90LHlUBAATeRgwTzENcWgLeng9ZiwAZjVhMQBHQXlysnYSCvJKhMtNJoB1MTgACzaySoAeABUAPnYTEAQFhE95aUzoLGQEAG0AaQQxKHUtHWbsSoBdNQm7MwshESLDgHN5OAAlON9M8gVkNXh8lAnlQ1EZtr9-nBAU9LlJPI0EOYQPdRBJnq8PjFvhCjtpdEEqiCEP0hiMzmMoY0pjdkcJUZIXu9Pp5sfI-kgoQcnggAD64k4EzrGUALZZwQSeQ5gra-WGUpqmGlIujQMqoZCYr7sRmalk2CqdGlAA)